# Linux command within AWK

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Im parsing a CSV file and want to add a md5sum of 2 columns at the end.

```
eval $(awk -F, -v OFS=", " 'NR==1{print $0,"FILENAME,DATE_LOADED,TEST";next}{ print $0 ", "ENVIRON["FILE"]", "ENVIRON["ISODATE"]", " $5$7 }' $FILE > $NAME"_ready.csv")
```

I have tried this, but no success

```
eval $(awk -F, -v OFS=", " 'NR==1{print $0,"FILENAME,DATE_LOADED,TEST";next}{ print $0 ", "ENVIRON["FILE"]", "ENVIRON["ISODATE"]", " $(md5 -s $5$7) }' $FILE > $NAME"_ready.csv")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a command in awk and capture it's output, use `cmd | getline`. The following should work for your case

```
awk -F, -v OFS=", " 'NR==1 {
                             print $0,"FILENAME,DATE_LOADED,TEST";
                             next
                           }
                           { 
                             line=$0
                             cmd="md5 -s "$5$7
                             cmd | getline
                             md5sum=$0
                             print line, ENVIRON["FILE"], ENVIRON["ISODATE"], md5sum
                           }' $FILE > $NAME"_ready.csv"
```

Comment: sorry one more questions. how i remove all the whitespaces from $5$7 ?